# How do I center align?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://github.com/ProjectCubit/website.git

I have a little problem that I just cannot seem to solve.
How do I center align? I tried various methods, but nothing seem to work.
I tried position: absolute, flex, and other methods from W3. Sorry, if this seems like a silly question.

I'm a bit new to Programming, thanks.

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
```

```css
.header_logo {
  width: 110px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}

body{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}




/*Reset*/

/* colors 8a3aff, 6f79ff, 3a9fff black-> 1f4568  grey->8198ae*/
.sect{
padding: 90px 0;
position: relative;
}


.collapse{
display: block;
}

.sect--grey{
/*background-color: #ebeff9;*/
}

.sect--violet{
background-color:#6f79ff;
}

.sect--padding-bottom{
padding-bottom:115px;
}

.sect--padding-top{
padding-top:90px;
}

.row--center{
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.row--margin{
margin-top:45px;
}

.row__title{
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: 400;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.row__sub{
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 0px; 
color: #8198ae;
}




/*menu header*/
.header{
padding: 30px 25px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.header__elenco {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__menu {
  float: right;
}
.header__el{
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header__logo, .header__menu{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.header__title{
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 18px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.header__light{
color: #8198ae;
}
.header__link{
color: #1f4568;
font-size: 14px;

}
.header__link:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color:#3a9fff;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
background-color: black;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  margin: 5px 0;
}



.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}





@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
.collapse{
display: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.header__container{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.header__menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.header{
  background-color:#fff; 
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
}
.header__logo{
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
}
.header__el {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.header .btn--white, .header .btn--white:hover{
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.header__el--blue{
  background-color:#3a9fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>WEB 3.0 Payments Infrastructure - Brix</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="Brix provides a set of Tools for Businesses and Developers to integrate Cryptocurrency payments and payouts in their Solutions.">
      <meta name="keywords" content="Cryptocurrency, Blockchain, Payments">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://image.ibb.co/fOur3b/favicon.png"/>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>
    <body>
<!--Navbar-->
    
  <body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container header__container">
  <div class="header__logo"><img class="header_logo" src="./images/branding/Brix_Logo.svg"></div> 
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
    
    <div class="header__menu">
      <nav id="navbar" class="header__nav collapse">
        <ul class="header__elenco">
          <li class="header__el"><a href="#" class="header__link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="header__el"><a href="#" class="header__link">Products</a></li>
          <li class="header__el"><a href="#" class="header__link">Brix for Consumers</a></li>
          <li class="header__el"><a href="#" class="header__link">About us</a></li>
  <a href="" class="btn btn--white">Contact Us →</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
      </div>
  </header>
  <!---->
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="text">
  <p>Nachos are</p>
  <p>
    <span class="word wisteria">tasty.</span>
    <span class="word belize">wonderful.</span>
    <span class="word pomegranate">fancy.</span>
    <span class="word green">beautiful.</span>
    <span class="word midnight">cheap.</span>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  </body>
  <!-- partial -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
    

</html>
```

Comment: so u want to center align them in a column wise, right? or row-wise?

Comment: I wanna horizontally align them in center.

Comment: If by "W3" you mean w3schools, please look for other resources like MDN instead.

Comment: but its already aligned tho..

Comment: Yea, I updated the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element

Comment: Do you mean center the <p> inside the page? Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for that.

Comment: didn't work, idk what's wrong.

Comment: @Reino Do you want to center .text inside the page or center the p inside the .text or both ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/3hwsfp69/

Comment: https://github.com/ProjectCubit/website.git

Comment: In StackOverflow you should always post the code, in your question & not just a link.

Comment: I posted the code initially, but it didn't allow me to post full, so I posted the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align: center;`, and `<br>` if you want. Here's a snippet:

```css
.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Nachos are</p><br/>
  <p>
    <span>tasty.</span><br/>
    <span>wonderful.</span><br/>
    <span>fancy.</span><br/>
    <span>beautiful.</span><br/>
    <span>cheap.</span><br/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here it's all in one line:

```css
.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Nachos are</p>
  <p>
    <span>tasty.</span>
    <span>wonderful.</span>
    <span>fancy.</span>
    <span>beautiful.</span>
    <span>cheap.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, the OP wants to align them in a row

Comment: yes, I edited in an option for that too.

Comment: It's still unclear how OP wants the elements aligned. And you're still using a fixed width of 450px which was the failed attempt of OP to center the text. That's why I downvoted. The proper solution is most likely this: https://jsfiddle.net/3hwsfp69/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align inline all in one line, and center it in the middle of the page
you can use flex to your parent only;

```
.text {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work.

Comment: Be sure you are editing on the same file, do this with inspect element, and you will achieve what you want.

Comment: @Reino, please post a screenshot of what happens when you use flex.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your code & it centers after adding `text-align: center` to `.text`.

Adding `flex` to `.text` does not work for the following reason:
The 2nd `<p>` containing the `span.word` **has 0 width & height, due to its children being absolutely positioned**. In order for flex to work you need to set appropriate width & height to the 2nd `<p>`.

But `text-align: center` unlike `flex` is inherited by all descendants, and not just the children.